# Designing Portrait Game for Iphone X in Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, iphone-x

I am attempting to make a game in unity and have been playing around with the notch of my new iPhone X. I understand that there are new safety margins that we have to now place UI elements in order to make sure they are not being cropped off by the notch or home gesture bar.

When I try and place a UI element near the top right of the screen, however, the placement is going to look different on iPhone X then on iPhone 7.

For example, if I place a UI element 35 units down and to the left of the right edge of the screen. On an iPhone7 the UI element will be placed 35 units down from the top of the usable screen whereas on the iPhoneX the UI element will be placed a total of 35 units minus the screen notch height from the top of the usable screen (lets say 5 units if the notch is 20 units)

Here is an image of what I am talking about:
[image]
[image]

SO my question is, how do I make the UI element 35 from the top of the "usable" screen? I guess the problem I have with the current solution is that if the game is run on a phone that has no notch, there will be a big blank space at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I found a solution, not a perfect solution but still a solution. I am first detecting if the device is a generation X iPhone and if this is true set the y position of the UI element to the Screen.safeArea.max.y position.

I would still like to see other solutions to this.

Here is my code:

```
if (UnityEngine.iOS.Device.generation == UnityEngine.iOS.DeviceGeneration.iPhoneX)
        {
            theImage.transform.position = new Vector2(theImage.transform.position.x, Screen.safeArea.max.y);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Unity's Screen.safeArea method to get the generic safe area of any iPhone. Use this to create a reactive safe area parent panel, then create your child image anchored 35 pixels out from the top right of the safe panel.

This will be a more generic solution than hardcoding to a device, as future versions of the iPhone X (Xs, Xs Max, XR) and other notched Android phones may not have the same sized notch. It will also account for the Home indicator and side safe areas when in landscape mode.

This requires Unity 2017.2.1+. The safe area panel should be a full screen UI panel (Anchor 0,0 to 1,1; Pivot 0.5,0.5). Also recommended to have your Canvas set to "Scale With Screen Size" and "Match (Width-Height)" = 0.5, in order to match any screen size and orientation.

You can use this script for the safe area parent panel:

```
public class SafeArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    RectTransform Panel;
    Rect LastSafeArea = new Rect (0, 0, 0, 0);

    void Awake ()
    {
        Panel = GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
        Refresh ();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        Refresh ();
    }

    void Refresh ()
    {
        Rect safeArea = GetSafeArea ();

        if (safeArea != LastSafeArea)
            ApplySafeArea (safeArea);
    }

    Rect GetSafeArea ()
    {
        return Screen.safeArea;
    }

    void ApplySafeArea (Rect r)
    {
        LastSafeArea = r;

        Vector2 anchorMin = r.position;
        Vector2 anchorMax = r.position + r.size;
        anchorMin.x /= Screen.width;
        anchorMin.y /= Screen.height;
        anchorMax.x /= Screen.width;
        anchorMax.y /= Screen.height;
        Panel.anchorMin = anchorMin;
        Panel.anchorMax = anchorMax;
    }
}
```

For a more in depth breakdown, I've written a detailed article with screenshots here: https://connect.unity.com/p/updating-your-gui-for-the-iphone-x-and-other-notched-devices. Hope it helps!